# Cancel current/active query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In my project I am running a massive query returning lots of data. Due to the size of this query, the runtime sometimes exceeds 1 minute. Ignoring other issues this may create, is there any way to cancel a currently running query?

For example, the user starts the query and is redirected to a standard 'Loading Results...' page. If they then decide that they no longer want the results, they can click a 'Cancel' button which will somehow terminate the running query.

Is this possible and how can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: It's pretty low-level, but have you considered [pg_cancel_backend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE)?

Comment: If you add this as an answer, I would be more than happy to mark it as correct.

Comment: Additionally, do you know of any way to be able to track a query with Postgres? For example, I can start a query but is there any way to get the process ID of the query without having to search through 'pg_stat_activity'?

Comment: No, I don't and two minutes of googling didn't turn up any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [pg_cancel_backend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL-TABLE).

From the docs:

> Cancel a backend's current query. You can execute this against another backend that has exactly the same role as the user calling the function. In all other cases, you must be a superuser.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is to restart the database, although sometimes you can send a cancel signal, depending on the DB setup. You could look at the rack-timeout gem perhaps?

The real issue is that your query should not take that long, and I would strongly advise not approaching the problem this way. A far better way would be to examine the query and attempt to optimise it. There are few, if any queries that should legitimately be taking >1 minute to complete. Get a dump of the data onto your local machine and run EXPLAIN on the query to find the bottlenecks. I have gotten large 142s queries down to <3s by adding the right indexes, so I would be amazed if you cannot get the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I'm looking in to running EXPLAIN on my queries and it's very helpful. Although this doesn't explain how to cancel the current query, it will help in speeding queries up. Thanks again.

Comment: Two things I disagree with in this answer: bouncing the database to kill the running query is overkill unless you are the only user on the db and you don't know about `pg_cancel_backend()` and `pg_terminate_backend()` (pg_cancel_backend has been around since pg 8.0), and secondly that queries should rarely run longer than 1 minute. If you are dealing with small datasets, sure, but if you are dealing with very large datasets or complex queries >1min can be the norm. Tuning your queries I totally agree with.

Comment: @bma Agree that restart is overkill. I wasn't really suggesting that :) I'd say that even with large/complex queries and datasets, >1 min is still a problem. Given that Facebook runs on MySQL and gets very fast response times, large datasets clearly need not be a problem. Complex queries may need to be broken into smaller ones, or the table structure may need optimising (nosql maybe?), but it's still possible.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this recently (adding a "cancel" button to our application). The plpgsql function I hacked together is below, which is basically a wrapper around the `pg_cancel_backend()` function.

Caveats:

1). Your application must create an unique id (or UUID) and pass that in to the function as the "p_uid" parameter.

2). I hardcoded the application user (that doesn't change).

3). Postgresql 9.0+ (this was created for 9.2, untested in any earlier versions)

4). Security could be tightened up a bit in the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cancel_user_query(p_uid TEXT, OUT retval BOOLEAN) RETURNS boolean
AS $function$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    /*  The pg_sleep() call at the start is because if a user issues a query
        then promptly tries to kill it, it will likely not have shown up in the
        pg_stat_activity view yet (there is a delay before it appears).
        XXX: The GUC setting "track_activities" *MUST* be enabled for this to work.
    */

    retval := FALSE;
    IF ( current_setting('track_activities')::BOOLEAN IS NOT TRUE ) THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[PUBLIC.CANCEL_USER_QUERY] - "track_activities" *MUST* be enabled for this to work';
        RETURN;
    END IF;

    /* In a system under regular high load, this might need to be bumped higher than 2 seconds */
    PERFORM pg_sleep(2); 

    WITH q AS ( SELECT pid FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE LOWER(usename) = 'YOUR_APP_USER' AND application_name = p_uid AND state <> 'idle' )
    SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid) AS retval
    INTO retval
    FROM q;

    if ( retval IS NOT TRUE ) then
        retval := FALSE;
    end if;

    RETURN;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
        RAISE WARNING '[PUBLIC.CANCEL_USER_QUERY] - ERROR: %',sqlerrm;
        retval := FALSE;
        RETURN;
END;
$function$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

On click of the "Cancel query" button, the application executes the function and checks the returned status.
Eg. `SELECT retval FROM public.cancel_user_query('asifdaqiwaviafasdf') retval`

Comment: Excellent. @bma, this looks very promising! Thank you for the code. How did you keep track of the 'p_uid' to pass in? I'm thinking that if there are multiple users executing queries at the same time, I want to be able to only cancel the query that is meant to be cancelled.

Comment: We have a big Java app and for this to work correctly, the session details are stored as the user navigates from page to page. We overloaded that session data with the uid of the report called by the user with an additional point: if the user left the page, then the query was automatically sent the cancel command. I'm not sure how the implementation was done in detail, I left that up to the Java devs. Oh, one other thing: our application role in the database has a role-level setting that any queries running longer than 5 minutes will be killed. This is done using `statement_timeout=5min`.