# Rails - Correct way to kill a running query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

First time running queries in rails console...

I had a query run accidentally: something like this

```
User.where(:location => 'US'))
```

which apparently is pulling me quite amount of data.

Now the query is still hanging there. I know I could just close this session and restart another. But I just would like to know the safest way to kill a query. Is there something similar like in mysql :

```
show full processlist
```

and

```
 kill #
```

Comment: if you are in rails console then you should be able to stop a process by command+c for mac and ctrl+c for windows

Comment: @Mandeep and `Ctrl-D` for exit from rails console

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel current/active query in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067095/cancel-current-active-query-in-ruby-on-rails) - not sure which db you are using

Comment: @Зелёный Never tried it but yep just tested ctrl+d on mac will exit rails console.

Comment: @Mandeep  thanks.. but it doesnt seem to be working. Nothing happened when i pressed cmd+c. no outputs or anything.

Comment: @peipei check this http://ss64.com/osx/syntax-bashkeyboard.html. It'll be ctrl+c for mac also. Wrote it wrong

Comment: @Mandeep ctr+c did not work either. I know ctr+c usually works in mysql too. really weird.. not sure if my session freezes.

Comment: @peipei when ctrl+C doesn't work, I normally go to a bigger hammer and use ctrl+Z

Answer (score 9):

When I want to stop a long running query, I typically just go up the chain of interrupts.

`ctrl c` will send SIGINT and hopefully just take you out of the current query or loop in the console. But, sometimes, this won't work so I go up a step to

`ctrl \` which will send SIGQUIT to quit the current process. This command will exit out of the rails console and back in to the terminal (assuming you launched the console from `rails c`)

As a worst case scenario I will go to use `ctrl z` which will suspend the process allowing you to find the process ID (using `top` or `ps` or whatever else) and then use `kill` on that pid. If that doesn't work the final thing to use is `kill -9` which will kill the process.